# vitest failed to mock quasar

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs3, vite, quasar-framework

I am having [vue3](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html) app with [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) and [vitest](https://vitest.dev/api/) and trying to mock the Quasar `useQuasar` composable which I am using in my custom Composable like:

```js
// useLoginRequestBuilder.ts
import { makeUserAuthentication } from "@/main/factories"
import { useQuasar } from "quasar"

export function useLoginRequestBuilder() {
  const $q = useQuasar()

  async function login() {
    try {
      $q.loading.show()
      const auth = makeUserAuthentication()
      return await auth.signinRedirect()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      $q.loading.hide()
      $q.notify({
        color: "red-4",
        textColor: "white",
        icon: "o_warning",
        message: "Login Failed!",
      })
    }
  }

  return {
    login,
  }
}
```

and I am trying to mock `quasar` in tests like:

```js
// useLoginRequestBuilder.spec.ts

import { useLoginRequestBuilder } from "@/main/builders"

vi.mock("quasar", () => ({ // <--- this is not really mocking quasar
  useQuasar: () => ({
    loading: {
      show: () => true,
      hide: () => true,
    },
  }),
}))

const spyAuth = vi.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true))

vi.mock("@/main/factories", () => ({
  makeUserAuthentication: () => ({
    signinRedirect: () => spyAuth(),
  }),
}))

describe("test useLoginRequestBuilder", () => {
  test("should call signinRedirect", async () => {
    const { login } = useLoginRequestBuilder()
    const sut = await login()
    expect(sut).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

`vi.mock("quasar"...` is failing to mock quasar and I am getting below error. That means, it failed to mock and failed to get the `$q.loading....` object.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loading')
```

I understand that there is a separate testing lib for quasar, [here](https://testing.quasar.dev/packages/unit-jest/) but I think this is not really the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Bordering on a necro-post, but I had a similar issue that the mocking factory wasn't creating the plugins being used in non-Vue components, and had to mock each call individually in the end.

Though I'd add it here for anyone else

```
vitest.mock("quasar", () => vi.fn()); // this doesn't mock out calls

// use individual mocks as below
import { Loading } from "quasar";
vi.spyOn(Loading, "show").mockImplementation(() => vi.fn());
vi.spyOn(Loading, "hide").mockImplementation(() => vi.fn());
```